# How to distinguish the meaning of the word "before" in different texts?

Tags: vocabulary

I know "before" could be used meaning "not after or present" or "in front of". how can I distinguish these two meanings?

As an example, what does *before* mean in the novel "[Me before you](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/15507958-me-before-you)" by Jojo Moyes?

Comment: Is that the title of a novel? You should cite the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With just those three words, you can´t distinguish. You need the context. You need to read the book to discover it. But ...

Let's assume that you are talking about **[Me before you](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Me_Before_You)** by Jojo Moyes.
I can offer you how the title was translated to Spanish. We use an equivalent word for "before": **antes**. But we have different structures to differentiate the meanings that you have listed.

Yo ante ti - (Me in front of you)

**Yo antes de ti** - (Me before meeting you for the first time)

Yo antes que tú - (My needs, my feelings, my family, my interests are more important to me than yours. I'm a bit selfish)

The title was translated: ***Yo antes de ti***, that is an exact translation for "Me before you" meaning more or less "how was my life before I met you". If the book describes a relevant change in the life of one of the character after meeting the other, we have a winner.